# Detect internet disconnection via socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Currently I'm using `node.js` server which has TCP socket connection(using `socket.io`) using this I'm showing real-time data via browser.

Consider a scenario, I have logged in to my application and all real-time is shown via web browser.  Now all of a sudden the network got disconnected.  At that I would like to show a message saying "Expired" when the client-side socket emits the **`disconnect`** event.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log("Disconnected from the server");
            alert("disconnect");
        });
```

Now my problem:  the above `disconnect` event is emitted after 60 seconds; In-between when user tries to update, it will not work and this will create a bad impression for us.

How to overcome this situation and how to emit the `disconnect` event all of a sudden when network got disconnected?

Comment: This is, in general, not possible.  How could your app be notified 'all of a sudden' when some router in another country crashes?  The network/protocol will try to reroute your data and this takes time.

Comment: @MartinJames It is possible.  Already when I close/refresh the browser it is triggering the "disconnect" event; *whereas when I try disconnect the network cable, it is triggering the same disconnect event after 60secs.*  So my problem is the **delay** and this is due to heartBeat pulse between browser/node and socket.io which is explained clearly in the below answer.  Hope you got my point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand `heartbeat interval` and `heartbeat timeout`. Earlier is the time when server emits a **heartbeat** each 25 seconds (by default). And later is timeout for server to keep that specific client in memory. If client receives the heartbeat within `heartbeat timeout` (60 seconds by default) it tells the server that I'm alive. If client doesn't receive a heartbeat from server within this timeout then server flushes that client out of memory and `disconnect` event is fired automatically on client side. This timeout is set when client connects to server. So you can set these properties in your Node.js server like this:

```
var socket = require('socket.io').listen(80,{
  'heartbeat interval': 5,
  'heartbeat timeout' : 10
});
```

Now server will emit heartbeat every 5 seconds and if client doesn't receive a heartbeat in 10 seconds, disconnect event will be fired. But remember that heartbeat interval should be less than heartbeat timeout. Hope this will work!

Comment: 1000+ thanks for the explanation :)  Here does reducing the *heartBeat* interval has any adverse effect in any part my app?

Comment: Yes you can say that, because server will be more busy in this case but that depends on your hardware configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
var io = require('socket.io')
  .listen(server, {'pingTimeout':4000, 'pingInterval':2000});
```